# Cant validate dynamic form with php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a problem with validating my dynamic html form using my php script. When I push submit, it says that there is undefined index, but this index is defined. My question different from others, because I'm trying to write all this code to the single php file. What's wrong with my code?

**My HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" action="/vehicles/add">  
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
            <tr>  
                <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" required></td>  
                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
            </tr>  
        </table>  
    </div>  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />  
</form>
```

**My jquery script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      });
```

**My PHP script:**

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $fields = count($_POST["name"]);
    for($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
        if(trim($_POST["name"][$i] != ''))  
           {  
                mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `vehicles` VALUES('', '$_POST[name][$i]', 0)"); 
           }  
    }
}
```

**My error:**

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: submit in
```

Comment: What is the error message??

Comment: Why don't you like to use `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multidimensional arrays, you need to use the complex string syntax to substitute the value, so you have to put curly braces around it and quote the literal index.

```
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `vehicles` VALUES('', '{$_POST['name'][$i]}', 0)");
```

But it would be better to use a prepared query to prevent SQL injection.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES ('', ?, 0)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $name);
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $name) {
    if (trim($name) != '') {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

Comment: And it will fix my problem with undefined index ?

Comment: I don't see any use of `submit` in the code you posted. That's a different problem.